# AngularJS: Not able to store data to an object

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to store captured data from the form in an object using `angular-material` for dialog box with the form to capture.

Related part of the controller looks like

```
  $scope.attendees = [{
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: ""
   }];  

$scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
$mdDialog.show({
controller: DialogController,
templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
targetEvent: ev,
clickOutsideToClose:true,
fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
})
};

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
                $scope.hide = function() {
                  $mdDialog.hide();
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                  $mdDialog.cancel();
                };

                $scope.saveAttendee = function(attendee) {

                  str = JSON.stringify(attendee, null, 4);
                  $mdDialog.hide(attendee);

                  console.log('Attendee ' + str);

                  $scope.attendees.push(attendee);

                  console.log('Attendees ' + $scope.attendees);
                };
              }
```

Output for `Attendee` is correct but later it crashed on `push(attendee)` as `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` or `push` will overwrite added previously data (based on given answer)

Any tips on that?

Comment: Define `$scope.attendees` within `DialogController`.

Comment: @AlexK It will overwrite already added data to an array. I have updated OP with more info

Comment: Looks like the directive uses an isolate scope by default. In that case, you'll need to tell it to use the parent scope, where `attendees` is defined. In the options within `$mdDialog.show()`, try adding `scope: $scope` to link the directive with the parent scope.

Comment: @AlexK Based on that still is better to use `angular material` for that kind of job or just switch to plain `bootstrap` dialog modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `$scope.attendees` inside the controller.

```
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

$scope.attendees = [{
 firstName: "",
 lastName: "",
 email: "",
 phone: ""
}];     

$scope.hide = function() {
  $mdDialog.hide();
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
  $mdDialog.cancel();
};

$scope.saveAttendee = function(attendee) {

  str = JSON.stringify(attendee, null, 4);
  $mdDialog.hide(attendee);

  console.log('Attendee ' + str);

  $scope.attendees.push(attendee);

  console.log('Attendees ' + $scope.attendees);
};
}
```

What you saying about to send data from controller who calls the mdDialog, a alld a plnkr with a basic example.
[example plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/4xp8ojqEgRN1cEJQ0Nzn/)

cour code modificated should be.

```
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, attendees) {
    $scope.attendees = attendees;
    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.saveAttendee = function(attendee) {
      str = JSON.stringify(attendee, null, 4);
      $mdDialog.hide(attendee);
      console.log('Attendee ' + str);
      $scope.attendees.push(attendee);
      console.log('Attendees ' + $scope.attendees);
    };
  }
```

and in the controller who calls for example

```
$modal.show({
 // configuration like you have.
}).then(function(response){
   //when hide the modal
   $scope.attendees = response;
});
```

Check if out if this help.

Comment: Yeah, that works, kind of but is overwriting what was previously stored in the `$scope.attendees` instead adding as a new array record.

Comment: you want the dialog change parent $scope from controller invoked?

Comment: I want to store data and access it from the parent to display as a table.

Comment: how do you implement the dialog, let me imagine you have a list of users, and if you want add anhother fire the dialog, push data in the html for the dialog, and save, the saved needs to return the users data. from previos invoke?

Comment: I have a list of user (empty) then I want to add an user using dialog, save it (add that user to the array) and then display a table of added users after closing dialog box. All is under the same controller. This is the main idea but first I'm not able to create that array to display desired table.

Comment: are you using angular-material for the dialog?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151915/discussion-between-jacktheknife-and-jesus-carrasco).

Comment: a will put a plkn in the answer on how you could call the mdDialog and send dhe $scope.attendees, and how resolve promise.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need "fixed" code for the dialog box controller is below

```
    var attendee = this;
    attendees = [];

    $scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        controllerAs: 'attendee',
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        locals: {parent: $scope}
    })
    .then(function(response){
        attendees.push(response);

        console.log(attendees);
        console.log(attendees.length);
    })
  };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

        var attendee = this;

        $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.save = function(response) {
            $mdDialog.hide(response);
        };
    }
```